# How to apply moment.js to existing variables in html

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

Is there a way to form the current date and time into a moment.js using these variables?

```
var x = new Date(document.lastModified);

var y = new Date();

document.writeln('The last modified date is: ' + x + ' and Date is: ' + y);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const last = moment(document.lastModified, "MM/DD/YYYY");
const now = moment();
document.write('The last modified date is: ' + last.format("YYYY-MM-DD") + ' and Date is: ' + now.format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey! Do you know how what i can do to show the time as well? @CertainPerformance

Answer (score 0):

You can use `n.toISOString();` to convert your date to ISO format and then parse it in momentjs.

```
var date = moment(n.toISOString()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Example:

```
var n = new Date();
n.toISOString();
var date = moment(n.toISOString()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
console.log(date);
```

Comment: Or just provide the Moment constructor a second argument.